# Aplicativo phonegap não faz requisição ajax com protocolo HTTP, somente com HTTP´s

Tags: ajax, apache-cordova

Tenho um aplicativo criado em Phonegap, no entanto não consigo fazer uma requisição com ele usando o protocolo HTTP, só consigo fazer a requisição com protocolo HTTPs, alguém tem alguma ideia de como concertar isso ?

Comment: E não é melhor fazer em HTTPS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não informou em que sistema isso esta ocorrendo se é no Android, iOS ou ambos.

Se esse problema estiver ocorrendo no Android, ele pode estar sendo causado por causa da recente alteração nas [configurações de segurança](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#CleartextTrafficPermitted).

Essa alteração deixa protocolos inseguros bloqueados por padrão.

---

### Casos em que você tem acesso ao manifest.xml

Se seu aplicativo utiliza o protocolo **HTTP** você vai precisa colocar em seu **manifest.xml**  [`android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#usesCleartextTraffic) na tag [`<application>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element), ficando +/- assim:

```xml
<application 
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    .
    . 
    .
```

Essa propriedade vai fazer seu aplicativo aceitar qualquer conexão HTTP.

Se você quiser ser mais especifico e permitir apenas que alguns domínios possa utilizar HTTP você terá que utilizar essa outra propriedade [`android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/meu_arquivo_de_configuracao`](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config). 
Nessa propriedade você informa o arquivo xml que contem as informações de segurança, Exemplo de configuração:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

<sup>[Veja mais sobre isso clicando aqui](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config)</sup>

---

#### Seu caso - PhoneGap / cordova

No caso como você esta utilizando o **PhoneGap**, você terá que fazer algo do tipo em sua **config.xml** para configura a propriedade `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`

```xml
<platform name="android">
  <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
      <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
  </edit-config>
</platform>
```

Vou deixar aqui o link para uma [pergunta similar do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54752716/2456894), pois pode ser que você precise alterar mais coisas em seu **config.xml**.

---

#### Outras possíveis soluções

<s>**Alternativa 1:**</s>

Você pode tentar mudar o `targetSdkVersion` para uma versão de API entre `24` e `27`.

**Observação**: Ao fazer isso talvez seja necessário também mudar coisas como `implementation` em seu arquivo **build.gradle**.
 Exemplo de um `implementation` de biblioteca de support:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.0'
}
```

> **Observação**: Se o objetivo é publicar seu aplicativo no Google Play a *Alternativa 1* não é mais válida pois o [Google Play passou a exigir](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469#targetsdk) que o `targetSdkVersion` esteja pelo menos na **API de nível 28** a partir de:
>
> - **01/08/2019** para novos apps.
> - **01/11/2019** para atualizações de apps.

**Alternativa 2:**

Como você esta utilizando AJAX, possa ser que seu servidor não esteja configurado para aceitar [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) (*Cross-Origin Resource Sharing*) quando responde a requisições via HTTP. Essa configuração depende do servidor usado por seu serviço aqui no SOpt tem [algumas repostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bcors%5d%20configurar) que podem ajudar a configura.