# React-Native: FlatList não renderiza dados JSON em celular com apk instalado

Tags: javascript, react, react-native, apk

Olá estou com um problema um pouco esquisito... tenho um apk gerado em modo release com assinatura tudo ok,mas quando instalo em meu celular um Xiomi redmi 7 na tela home não redenriza a flatlist onde eu busco os dados via JSON em um servidor externo... Instalei em 3 celulares onde ja foram usados Depuração e nem um deles funcionou sendo o outro Xiome redmiNote 8 e uma Assus... Ai parte para a coisa esquisita rsrs, instalando o APK em outros celulares a flatlist funciona buscando os dados e renderizando-os  conforme codificados em meu index.

Qualquer ideia do que seja vai ser bem vinda...

```
//
const [filteredDataSource, setFilteredDataSource] = useState([]);//filtrando dados do json
const [listars, setListars] = useState([]);//array do json
const[isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);//reload view 

useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    fetch('http://serverteste:8092/json/')  
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      setFilteredDataSource(responseJson);
      setListars(responseJson);
    })
    .catch(() => Alert.alert('Erro ao buscar Acessos'))
    .finally(() => setIsLoading(false));
}, []
);
```

Minha flatList

```
        <View style={styles.container}> 
            {isLoading ? (
              <View style={[styles.containerAcrt, styles.horizontal]}>
                <ActivityIndicator
                      animating = {true}
                      color = '#bc2b78'
                      size = "large"
                      />
                      
              </View>

            ): (
                <FlatList
                data={filteredDataSource}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                renderItem={ItemView}
                />
            )
            }
          </View>
```

| Aqui esta um print da flatlist renderizada em um celular limpo nunca usado depuração ou usado para desenvolvimento | Este é o print da tela do aplicativo em meu celular |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Aqui esta um print da flatlist renderizada em um celular limpo nunca usado depuração ou usado para desenvolvimento] | [image: Este é o print da tela do aplicativo em meu celular] |

Observações:

- Em relação a permissões do lado do servidor já foi verificado e esta tudo ok...
- Os testes feito em meus celulares estavam em redes diferente da rede local onde fica hospedado o servidor entao ja descarta qualqeur conflito de faixa de IP.
- quando rodo aplicação em mode DEBUG funciona normalmente.

desde de ja agradeço que poder da uma luz do que pode ser...

Comment: Possivelmente relacionado: [Aplicativo phonegap não faz requisição ajax com protocolo HTTP, somente com HTTP´s \[fechada\]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/388674/3774)

Answer (score 1):

Sua requisição é HTTP se o Android for 10, ele tem uma proteção quando gera o build, você tem que liberar esse tipo de requisição no **AndroidManifest.xml**
Na tag `application` adicione a propriedade `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`

Comment: Entendi vou configurar isso, desde ja muito obrigado mesmo!!